# unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error

hey I am newbie to ruby on rails and I am trying run a simple program from this blog and facing lot of problems error. 
http://goodbadtech.com/2009/05/13/ruby-on-rails-import-csv-data-into-database/
Could not able to figure out the solution.

Here is the error log.

```
/home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load': /home/jeevan/csv/config/routes.rb:64: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `block in load_paths'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `each'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `load_paths'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:13:in `reload!'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `block in initialize'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `call'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `execute_if_updated'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Finisher>'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:64:in `call'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:64:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /home/jeevan/csv/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/jeevan/csv/config.ru:4:in `require'
        from /home/jeevan/csv/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from /home/jeevan/csv/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from /home/jeevan/csv/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
        from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Please help me out in this

Comment: There will be a missing `end` somewhere, and it is detected at line 64.

Comment: @mliebelt Wrong way around ;-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This means there is a *syntax error* and translates to "the `end` keyword was found when nothing more was expected to complete the program". This is usually due to an unbalanced number of "openers". For instance,

foo.rb: ([demonstration](http://codepad.org/n0SMQsjZ))

```
if true
  puts "hello world"
  end   # the indent
end     # is a lie
```

> Line 4: syntax error, unexpected kEND [keyword_end], expecting $end

Happy coding.

Comment: "expecting $end" is not ruby end keyword, its a bison parser error.

Answer (score 4):

While this is typically a syntax error, I've encountered the exact same error message due to an unknown issue with a gem in my RVM gemset. If you see no syntax errors, try deleting and recreating your gemset.

Answer (score 0):

I've also gotten this without having an extra `end` by omitting a comma from routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error. Found out, it was due to my editor changing the quotes `"` 'smartly' in the mac editor.