# Ruby syntax error: unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I am supposed to:

- Capitalize the first letter of string.
- Capitalize every word except articles (`the`, `a`, `an`), conjunctions (`and`), and prepositions (`in`).
- Capitalize `i` (as in `"I am male."`).
- Specify the first word of a string (I actually have no idea what this means. I'm trying to  run the spec file to test other functions).

Here's my code:

```
class Book
  def initialize(string)
    title(string)
  end
  def title(string)
    arts_conjs_preps = %w{ a an the and
                           but or nor for
                           yet so although
                           because since
                           unless despite
                           in to
                           }
    array = string.downcase.split
    array.each do |word|
        if (word == array[0] || word == "i") then word = word.capitalize
        if arts_conjs_preps !include?(word) then word = word.capitalize
    end
    puts array.join(' ')
  end
end

puts Book.new("inferno")
```

Ruby says I'm messing up at:

```
puts Book.new("inferno") <--(right after the last line of code)
```

I get exactly the same error message with this test code:

```
def title(string)
    array = string.downcase.split
    array.each do |word|
        if word == array[0] then word = word.capitalize     
    end
  array.join(' ')
end

puts title("dante's inferno")
```

The only other Stack Overflow thread regarding this particular syntax error that did not suggest trailing or missing `end`s or `.`s as the root of the problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061789/unexpected-keyword-end-expecting-end-syntaxerror?rq=1). The last comment recommends deleting and recreating the gemset, Which sounds scary. And I'm not sure how to do.

Any thoughts? Simple solution? Resources to help?

**Solution**

```
class Book
    def initialize(string)
        title(string)
    end

    def title(string)
    arts_conjs_preps = %w{ a an the and
                       but or nor for
                       yet so although
                       because since
                       unless despite
                       of in to
                               }
    array = string.downcase.split
    title = array.map do |word|
          if (word == array[0] || word == "i") || !arts_conjs_preps.include?(word)  
            word = word.capitalize 
          else
            word
          end
        end
      puts title.join(' ')
    end
end

Book.new("dante's the inferno")
```

Answer (score 2):

Write as

```
class Book
  def initialize(string)
    title(string)
  end

  def title(string)
    arts_conjs_preps = %w{ a an the and
                           but or nor for
                           yet so although
                           because since
                           unless despite
                           in to
                           }
    array = string.downcase.split
    array.each do |word|
        word = word.capitalize if (word == array[0] || word == "i")
        word = word.capitalize if !arts_conjs_preps.include?(word)  
    end
    puts array.join(' ')
  end
end

puts Book.new("inferno")
# >> inferno
# >> #<Book:0x9704b7c>
```

There are 2 errors I can see :

- None of the `if` has `end` keyword at end.
- `if arts_conjs_preps !include?(word)` is not correct syntax.

As per your last comment change some part of the code:

```
    array = string.downcase.split
    array.map! do |word,ar|
        bol = !arts_conjs_preps.include?(word) || word == array[0] || word == "i"
        bol ? word.capitalize : word
    end
    puts array.join(' ')
  end
end

puts Book.new("inferno")
# >> Inferno
# >> #<Book:0x9e50bd8>
```

Comment: Okay - the code runs now. But for some reason the output is the same as the input. (I.e., the string is not capitalized.)

Comment: Arup Rakshit: I combined your solution with Sergio's (above), but generally speaking it did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All `if`'s should have matching `end`'s. Yours don't have any.

```
if (word == array[0] || word == "i") || !arts_conjs_preps.include?(word)
  word = word.capitalize
end
```

Alternatively, you can use modifier notation (since that is what you were probably going for)

```
word = word.capitalize if (word == array[0] || word == "i")
word = word.capitalize if !arts_conjs_preps.include?(word)
```

or

```
word.capitalize! if (word == array[0] || word == "i")
word.capitalize! unless arts_conjs_preps.include?(word)
```

Besides, you had invalid syntax in one of them.

```
if arts_conjs_preps !include?(word)
```

This is no valid syntax that I know of. (*If you meant to check if an element belongs to the array, using ruby standard library. It is perfectly valid ruby code otherwise*).

### Update with working code

Works this way

```
array = array.map do |word|
    if (word == array[0] || word == "i") || !arts_conjs_preps.include?(word) 
      word.capitalize
    else
      word
    end
end
```

Comment: Sergio - thanks for the recommendations. They match Arup's, which did get my code to run. Problem now is that the code isn't capitalizing the input string, which was the original purpose.

Comment: Regarding your reference to the Ruby Standard Library, you mean http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/? What, in particular, should I look for there? An article or instructions on #include? ...or something similar?

Comment: @user2839246: I meant this method: [Array#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F).

Comment: Sergio Tulentsev: I combined your solution with Arup's (below), but generally speaking it did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an **end** where you have written your **if**