# syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND

Tags: ruby

```
array = []
prime_cap = 2_000_000
prime_nums=(1..prime_cap).map do |p|
  array = unless p % p-1.downto(1):0
end
```

I'm new to ruby and I dont understand whats the problem, may you please explain why it says "untitled:5: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND" when I try to run it.

Comment: can you tell me what are you doing here `p % p-1.downto(1):0` ?

Comment: What's that unless line doing? Especially the colon zero?

Comment: Sorry, Here's my new code: prime_nums = []
(1..2000000).each {|p| prime_nums << p unless p% p-1.downto(1) == 0}
puts prime_nums.reduce(:+)

Comment: and what i'm doing is trying to sum the prime numbers under 2000000

Comment: Edit your question, don't try to wedge code into comments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unexpected keyword\_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061789/unexpected-keyword-end-expecting-end-syntaxerror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the modulo operation with an enumeration, you have to iterate over all elements.

```
prime_nums = []
(2..2_000_000).each do |p|
    prime_nums << p if (p-1).downto(2).none?{ |n| p % n == 0 }
end
```

Notice the brackets around `p-1` and also the method `none?`, which checks a condition for each element of an enumeration and returns a boolean.
Also, I used 2 instead of 1 for the iteration, because 1 isn't prime.

That said, there are more efficient algorithms for finding primes.
For example, you may want to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_eratosthenes or you could start the check with the square root of p, instead of `p-1`.